# How to add something to a favorite list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, view, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Favorite list where I can add different items but it doesn't work. I made a simple code to show you what's going on.

```
// BookData gets data from Json
struct BookData: Codable {
var titolo: String
var descrizione: String
}

class FavoriteItems: ObservableObject {
@Published var favItems: [String] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var bookData = BookDataLoader()
@ObservedObject var favoriteItems = FavoriteItems()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: FavoriteView()) {
                Text("Go to favorites")
            }
            ForEach(0 ..< bookData.booksData.count) { num in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(self.bookData.booksData[num].titolo)")

                    Button(action: {
                              self.favoriteItems.favItems.append(self.bookData.booksData[num].titolo)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct FavoriteView: View {
@ObservedObject var favoriteItems = FavoriteItems()

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach (0 ..< favoriteItems.favItems.count) { num in
            Text("\(self.favoriteItems.favItems[num])")
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I launch the app I can go to the Favorite View but after adding an Item I cannot.
My aim is to add an Item to Favorites and be able to save it once I close the app

Answer (score 0):

The view model favoriteItems inside ContentView needs to be passed into FavoriteView because you need a reference of favoriteItems to reload FavoriteView when you add a new data.

Change to

`NavigationView(destination: FavoriteView(favoriteItems: favoriteItems))` `@ObservedObject var favoriteItems: FavoriteItems`

It will be fine.

Thanks, X_X

Comment: I understand what you mean and it makes sense since I created another instance of FavoriteItems inside FavoriteView that's not linked to the ContentView.

Comment: The main problem is that I need to use coredata to add, save and delete items inside FavoriteView and I found that the main problem was accessing FavoriteView as a NavigationLink inside my ContentView so instead I assigned it to another tabItem in my tabBar and works perfectly :)